# what's the meaning of "While this debate is ever unfolding"?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "While this debate is ever unfolding"?

**While this debate is ever unfolding**, there is yet another boundary, the economic boundary, which divides and develops border identity

Answer (score 1):

By way of context, I note that the sentence under discussion comes from David Stea, Jamie Zech, and Melissa Gray, "[Change and Non-change in the U.S.-Mexican Borderlands after NAFTA](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mnc6pguW220C&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22While+this+debate+is+ever+unfolding,+there+is+yet+another+boundary,+the+economic+boundary,+which+divides+and+develops+border+identity%22&source=bl&ots=pE3nfqvMAU&sig=7YtsS1-Bt9KEohAZhqNVy9Nn65U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3J9hU5_iI4KyyAT8z4GwCg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22While%20this%20debate%20is%20ever%20unfolding%2C%20there%20is%20yet%20another%20boundary%2C%20the%20economic%20boundary%2C%20which%20divides%20and%20develops%20border%20identity%22&f=false)," in *Understanding Life in the Borderlands* (2010). The text immediately preceding the cited sentence does little to clarify what "this debate" refers to, but I gather that it involves an academic dispute over whether and to what extent a hybrid cultural identity exists along the U.S.–Mexico border.

Looking at the OP's question, I thought that perhaps the poster's confusion wasn't specifically over the "ever unfolding" component of the sentence, but over the "While ... ever" combination: The poster may be wondering why the author uses a seemingly time-specific (and time-limited) word like *while* in conjunction with a time-unlimited (that is, eternally applicable) word like *ever*.

*While* is a tricky conjunction in English because it can mean four distinct things: "during the time that"; "although" (that is, "despite the fact that"); "whereas" (that is, as Merriam-Webster puts it, "when on the one hand"); or "similarly and at the same time that" (Merriam-Webster's language again). So a reader is presented with four possible interpretations of the cited sentence:

> During the time that this debate is ever unfolding, there is yet another boundary, the economic boundary, which divides and develops border identity.

This version of the sentence is awkward because (as noted earlier) it unnecessarily focuses on the timing of an event that never ceases. Assuming that the authors are rational beings, they can hardly have intended to invite this interpretation.

> Although this debate is ever unfolding, there is yet another boundary, the economic boundary, which divides and develops border identity.

This version of the sentence puts the ever-unfoldingness of the debate over hybrid cultural identity in opposition to the issue of the economic boundary that exists at the border. But there is no reason to suppose that any opposition exists between the eternal unfolding of the debate and the existence of the economic boundary; objectively they appear to be separate (and indeed scarcely related) issues. This line of reasoning leads me to reject the second interpretation of *while*, too.

> Whereas this debate is ever unfolding, there is yet another boundary, the economic boundary, which divides and develops border identity.

This reading, like the "Although the debate..." reading, suffers from a false contrast between the way the cultural debate is unfolding and the plain fact of the economic boundary; I would discard it.

> Similarly and at the same time that this debate is ever unfolding, there is yet another boundary, the economic boundary, which divides and develops border identity.

This reading takes the opposite tack from the "Although..." and "Whereas..." readings, focusing on the similarity (and simultaneity) between the unfolding of the cultural debate and the existence of the economic border. The presence of *ever* returns as an annoyance here, and the argument that an ongoing debate and an existing economic divide somehow behave similarly is not one that I can make much sense of. Still, I suspect that this notion of *while* comes closest to the authors' intention.

If I were recasting the sentence to make maximum sense of it, I would put into these terms:

> Moving beyond the continuing debate over hybrid cultural identity, we turn to another major issue: the economic boundary, which both divides and fosters border identity.

The revamped sentence dispenses with the original sentence's *ever* (which I take to have been, in the final analysis, a verbal flourish harmful to the coherence of the authors' main argument), and it presents the discussion of the economic border as following on the discussion of hybrid border identity. I'm fairly confident that this is all that the authors wanted the cited sentence to convey.

Answer (score 0):

**While the debate continues**, there is yet another boundary, which divides and develops birder identity.

*Ever unfolding*, never ending because it appears  to have no solution.

[ever unfolding](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ever-unfolding) have a look here for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

It generally needs the hyphen, ever-unfolding, as it is an adjective formed of a compound verb.

But it means that as the debate continues, more aspects that need further debating continually arise.  The debate does not cycle, but constantly changes direction pursuing new directions, which impedes progress overall.

The analogy is to a complex work of, say, origami, where straightening out one part exposes others that are still more tightly folded.